# Maven Log4j not working , added dependency and log4j.properties

Tags: maven, logging, log4j

i have a project in spring and hibernate.
before converting project to maven log functionality was working fine
after converting a web project to maven log`s are not appending.
I have added maven dependency and it is visible in jars.
logger not giving any error
Please help ...

i have added this dependency in my pom

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `log4j.properties` file must be located in the following location:

```
src/main/resources/log4j.properties
```

Comment: it is located at same location